# jQuery change value if class=n

Tags: jquery, html, class

I want to change the value of a div container (number 1) if its class is equal to other div's (number 2) class value.

First of all, I get the value of div number 2:

```
  var classId = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
```

it has two classes, second one is I am using.

Next I try to compare the values and change the data inside div number 1:

```
$.ajax(test.base_url + "name/name/" + ID, {
cache: false,
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if ($("#redChar").attr("class") == classId) {
        $("#redChar").find('.'+classId).html(data);
    }
    else {
        $("#redChar").html();
    }

},
dataType:"html"
});
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: here `this` represents what? Means div number 2?

Comment: Solution seems correct, if `#redChar` has only one class. ***If so***, Try to debug your code, make sure your ajax returns success, and if if statement matches. ***If not*** - try to use `hasClass` method instead comparing `$("#redChar").attr("class")`.

Comment: It only works for the first #redChar, but not for the rest.
and $this represents div that has two classes.

Comment: **Your HTML is not valid.** You have to use different ids for multiple elements.

Comment: loler, thank you. I've used different IDs and now it works. Thank you and all who took time to help me, appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$("#redChar").hasClass(classId)`

Also, if you want to change the content of the `$("#redChar")`, you chould take out that `find()` and apply the changes directly to it : `$("#redChar").html(data);`

Comment: `hasClass()` gives Boolean value, he is comparing to get the Boolean value. Both are not same?

Comment: hasClass works when the div has multiple classes. Comparing the 'class' attribute does not.

Comment: this one:
if ($("#redChar").attr("class") == classId) {
      $("#redChar").html(data);
works well, but it changes value for div that has that ID, but when I try $("#redChar").hasClass(classId).html(data); it does not work.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I think I need to be more specific.
I have numerous DIVS with same ID, but I want to change the values inside where class value is the same as my classId variable and I want to change the value ONLY to that div that has that specific class.